# Access an array/map with index of enum class type (something like a constexpr map)

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap, stdarray, enum-class

Say I have a

```
enum class foo : std::uint32_t {
    a = 4711,
    b = 815,
    ...
};
```

with `n` enumeration constants. Assume that there actual numerical value is important. I need to pass precisely one value of type `T` to a function for every enumeration constant in `foo`.

I really would like to pack them together, for example in a `std::array<T, n> arr`, and access the `T` value corresponding to the enumeration constant `a` by `arr[a]`, and so on.

This would be possible, for example, if the constants would be valued by `0, 1, 2, ...`. Then I could write `arr[static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<foo>(a)]`. However, even then this is not as easy to read as `arr[a]`.

So, is there some kind of "`constexpr` map or something similar? The solution I'm looking for should not be specific for `foo`, but quite generic, since I have multiple such `foo` enum classes.

Comment: There's nothing in C++ that will do it automatically. Whenever I find myself needing something that goes outside of C++ boundaries I simply use additional tools to get the job done. In this case I would hack together some scripting that defines the enumerated values externally, in some structured format, like xml or yaml, and use a script to robo-generate the `enum class` declaration and an enumerated list of all the numeric values. C++ can do everything, but not everything can be done entirely in C++.

Comment: You might still wrap your array in a class, and move the cast into your `operator []`. minimal perfect hashing would be ideal. Simpler, if you are in `constexpr` is simply an ordered array with all enum value. a simple find giving the corresponding index.

Comment: so you want a custom container built on top of either std::map or std::vector of pairs